# What is the most effective way to filter this array?

Tags: javascript, filter

I have two arrays. My goal is to get a third array with users that exist in usersUpdated but do not exist in oldUsers. I know i have to apply multiple filters, but I do not know how.

```
   const oldUsers = [
     { name: 'Fede', id: 1 },
     { name: 'Marce', id: 2 },
  ];

   const usersUpdated = [
   { name: 'Fede', id: 1 },
   { name: 'Marce', id: 2 },
   { name: 'Ale', id: 3 },
   { name: 'Julian', id: 4 },
];


const expectedValue = [
  { name: 'Ale', id: 3 },
  { name: 'Julian', id: 4 }
 ];
```

Comment: Why do you need multiple filters? Just filter `usersUpdated` with the condition that it doesn't exist in `oldUsers`.

Comment: Your question is unclear : which is the reference for duplicates ? the Id or the name, or both ? if the Id is the same but  the names arre differentd sould the name to be updated ?

Comment: plus : in your examples, the tables are listed in ascending order on the value of the Id. is this a mandatory rule?

Answer (score 0):

Convert arrays to objects, use names as keys & ids as values,  delete keys of old obj from updated obj then convert the updated obj back to array.